# What is the etymology of the Hebrew word יָלַד

Tags: etymology, hebrew, semitic-languages

What is the etymology of the Hebrew word יָלַד, transliterated, *yalad*.  The [Hebrew Lexicon](http://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/Lexicon/Lexicon.cfm?strongs=H3205&t=KJV) offers no etymology.

This is an effort to research the linguistics pertaining to a question on BH-SE, [How can Three Questions be solved and the Math Still be Correct.](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/8365/how-can-the-3-questions-be-resolved-with-the-math-still-correct)
The solution requires that *begat* be understood as conception.

Answer (score 7):

The root w-l-d “to beget” (of a man) and “to give birth to” (of a woman) is found not only in Hebrew and Ethiopic, but in all Semitic languages (Akkadian, Hebrew, Aramaic, Arabic, South Arabian, Ethiopic etc.) The shift of initial w to y is regular in Hebrew and Aramaic.

Comment: Thank you.  How is this root defined in these languages?

Comment: It has the same meaning in all these languages: "beget" and "give birth to".

Answer (score 3):

It has cognates in many other Semitic languages, all with the same meaning "give birth", so I would say that that *is* the "essence of its meaning". (I've never seen this root used to mean "travail", by the way; if it's attested in that meaning somewhere, this is probably a secondary sense.)

The other two roots you mention are probably unrelated. *y-l-l* "howl" looks onomatopoeic, while *y-l-ʕ* (which seems to be a hapax, i.e. possibly a nonce creation in the single verse in which it appears) presumably comes from *loʕ* "mouth".

Comment: Indeed. Ethiopic ዎልዴ, "wolde" ("son of", in patronymics) is from the same root.